# TFS in VS2010 "remembers" file system mappings for deleted server/workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Using the TFS tools in VS2010, I had added a CodePlex server. I had mapped a project on there to a local path, say `C:\MyProject`  Later, we moved the project to a dedicated TFS server, so I added a new TFS server, and deleted the CodePlex one.  This in turn removed the "workspace" for it.

However, now if I try to map a project in the second TFS server to `C:\MyProject`, I get the error:

> The path C:\MyProject is already mapped in workspace MY-MACHINE;SND\myCodeplexUserName [https://tfs.codeplex.com/tfs/tfs32]

If I go to `File | Source Control | Workspaces...` in VS, that CodePlex workspace is not listed (since I had deleted the TFS server reference)

Does anyone know of another way to remove the existing mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command line utility `tf` with the `workspace` and `workspaces` commands. You may also find the `workfold` command useful.

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and type:

```
tf help workspace
```

I had to do this the other day to delete all the workspaces for a collection that was moved to a different server. In my case, the command was `tf workspace /delete /collection:<url>`. Use `tf workspaces` to display all your current workspaces.

Comment: That was a huge help, thank you! I actually had 2 workspaces with the same name, but listed under 2 different collection URLs. I just had to `tf workspaces` to get the collection url and workspace name, then `tf workspace /delete /collection:{collection url} {workspace name}`